# need to make my create post FBV not include the user currently signed in

Tags: django

hi guys so I just started studying django about 1.5 weeks ago so im like really new but I'm finally starting to understand the gist of everything and I wanted to test myself by making a blog app w/o help on tutorials on youtube and I did finish the app (like everything works) but theres one part thats really bugging me.  So in my create_post FBV, I wanted to make it so that when the signed in user makes a post, my postform doesn't show the username, but only the title and the content to create. but when I first excluded it, the post wouldn't create since the computer doesn't know who the user is. I tried looking stuff up for the longest time and what to do and not searching on youtube, but the best thing I could find was passing it initial. After i finished everything else I saw someone did it by using a CBV but i only just started reading the source code and documentation for like two days so I'm no where near comfortable with them. This is my code:

```
@login_required
def create_post(request):
    form = PostForm(initial={'author':request.user})

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST, initial={'author':request.user})
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect('blog-home')
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'posts/create_post.html', context)
```

so my postform has a user attribute which is a one-to-many relationship with the User so when I create a post on admin, I can choose among a whole list of users which is what i wanted. but on the blog site itself when I create a post as im already signed in, my code makes it that the drop down menu still shows but my username is just automatically filled in. so technically a user can post as a different user than who hes signed in as. I tried looking all over but couldn't find the solution other than using CBV. I can start reading on them a lot more but is there any way to do this with FBVs?

Comment: What does your PostForm look like? Add the code, please.

Answer (score 0):

you need to get the user before saving the the form.

```
@login_required
def create_post(request):

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = PostForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.user = request.user
        post.save()
    return redirect('blog-home')
context = {
    'form': form
}
return render(request, 'posts/create_post.html', context)
```

In post.user, the user is the name of the fields you define when getting the user as one-to-many in Post model.